# Interpret single line basic scripting code

Tags: regex

I've a very big file containing the following data structure, it's a very basic scripting language and I can't get to find a way to interpret or get complete structures for it.

Here's what the structure looks like:

```
# GAME MAP

00-01: Content={3555}
00-00: Content={1000, 1001, 1002 String="Some text.", 1003, 1004}
01-00: Content={1006, 1005 Amount=5}
02-00: Refresh, Content={1001, 1555 Content={1200, 1001 String="Text"}}
```

The structure is as follows:

BYTE-BYTE: Data, Content={OBJECT DATA}

OBJECT DATA Can contain other OBJECT DATA which is defined with "Content={}" as seen above, any ideas what can I do to interpret this? Doesn't matter the language I just need to see a way for it. (C# or C++ preferably).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parenthesized (nested) structure need a grammar to be parsed, a regular expression is not sufficient. (Theorically if you know in advance the max depth you could solve your problem with a regex but it would be quite complicated). Antlr or javaCC (Java) allow you to write parser that can do it.